# Apache won't run Py_Initialize(); function

Tags: python, c, apache2

How to run python functions into Apache module?

```
#include "httpd.h"
#include "http_config.h"
#include "http_protocol.h"
#include "ap_config.h"
#include "python2.7/Python.h"
static char* a(){
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("f = open('/tmp/workfile', 'w+')")
                        "f.write('0123456789abcdef')");
    Py_Finalize();
    return "Goog_Job\t";
}

/* The sample content handler */
static int mor_handler(request_rec *r)
{
    if (strcmp(r->handler, "mor")) {
        return DECLINED;
    }
    r->content_type = "text/html";         
    if (!r->header_only) {
        char *d;
        d = a();
        ap_rputs(d, r);
        ap_rputs("The sample page from mod_mor.c\n", r);}
        return OK;
    }
}

static void mor_register_hooks(apr_pool_t *p)
{
    ap_hook_handler(mor_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_MIDDLE);
}

/* Dispatch list for API hooks */
module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA mor_module = {
    STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF, 
    NULL,                  /* create per-dir    config structures */
    NULL,                  /* merge  per-dir    config structures */
    NULL,                  /* create per-server config structures */
    NULL,                  /* merge  per-server config structures */
    NULL,                  /* table of config file commands       */
    mor_register_hooks  /* register hooks                      */
};
```

It doesn't show anything in my browser with `http://localhost/mor`, although I have

```
LoadModule mor_module         /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mor.so
<Location /mor>
    SetHandler mor
</Location>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is so hard way !!.

Use python and mod_wsgi. It is very easy.
try this guide. 
http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide

Comment: Yes. Dear Ochirbold Manal, you already asked some apache+pyhon+c questions. What do you want to do? The apache module mod_wsgi works very good? Do you think you can get better performance?